# JSON output on string causes NoMethodError - undefined method `id' for #<String:***>:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, string, autocomplete

I have an array of strings like so.

```
trans_names = ["UBER US JUL01 YO3SW CA 16184", 
               "UBER US JUL01 HVRD2 CA 16186", 
               "UBER US JUL01 LIORT CA 16184", 
               "UBER US JUN26 UCF2Z CA 16180", 
               "UBER US JUN27 EZOF5 CA 16180", 
               "UBER US JUN25 BM3LO CA 16179",  
               "UBER US JUN23 5RNBI CA 16177"]
```

When I search the array for a word like "UBE" it should return json of the word I am typing. So it should return "UBER" just the word "UBER" not the entire string and only 1 instance of uber not 7 instances. Here is my controller method

```
   def get_autocomplete_items(params)
     @transaction = current_user.transaction
     @trans_array = @transaction.trans_names.find_all { |x| /#{Regexp.escape(params[:term])}/i =~ x }
     render json: @trans_array
   end
```

However, when my method runs the query it works but when I get to the line

```
render json: @trans_array
```

I get the error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `id' for #<String:0x007fa1af182cb8>:
```

How can I fix this and only show the one instance of the word within the string. There is no id for the strings. Only the strings in the array.

P.S> This a custom method for a rails_jquery_autocomplete

--EDIT--

controller.rb

```
class Tenants::TransactionsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    autocomplete :transaction, :trans_names, limit: 5, full: true

   def get_autocomplete_items(params)
      @transaction = current_tenant.user
      @trans_array = @transaction.trans_names.find_all { |x| /#{Regexp.escape(params[:term])}/i =~ x }
      render json: @trans_array
   end
end
```

When this method in the controller is run it gets me the array of only lines that match the user's input word BUT it doesn't output I  get the error about the string "id"

Here is the error

```
    Started GET "/users/transactions/autocomplete_transaction_trans_names?term=uber" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-18 11:06:20 -0500
Processing by Tenants::TransactionsController#autocomplete_transaction_trans_names as JSON
  Parameters: {"term"=>"uber"}
D, [2016-07-18T11:06:20.485530 #27984] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:27017 | true_numbers_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"tenants", "filter"=>{"deleted_at"=>nil, "_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('577ef257d2916212017af892')}, "limit"=>-1}
D, [2016-07-18T11:06:20.486304 #27984] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:27017 | true_numbers_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.000669s
D, [2016-07-18T11:06:20.487448 #27984] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:27017 | true_numbers_development.count | STARTED | {"count"=>"reportapprovals", "query"=>{"tenant_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('577ef257d2916212017af892')}}
D, [2016-07-18T11:06:20.488221 #27984] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:27017 | true_numbers_development.count | SUCCEEDED | 0.00067s
D, [2016-07-18T11:06:20.489481 #27984] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:27017 | true_numbers_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"transactions", "filter"=>{"deleted_at"=>nil, "tenant_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('577ef257d2916212017af892')}, "limit"=>-1}
D, [2016-07-18T11:06:20.600603 #27984] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:27017 | true_numbers_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.110952s
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 120ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `id' for #<String:0x007fa1af1c2570>:
  rails3-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.15) lib/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/autocomplete.rb:101:in `block in json_for_autocomplete'
  rails3-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.15) lib/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/autocomplete.rb:100:in `json_for_autocomplete'
  rails3-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.15) lib/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/autocomplete.rb:75:in `block in autocomplete'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:433:in `_run__2294321111111650643__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  client_side_validations (4.2.4) lib/client_side_validations/middleware.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__3629189788356106492__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.10) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.10) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.10) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.10) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.10) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.10) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/SupremeA/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/SupremeA/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/SupremeA/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

I can change my return array to Ruby objects and it comes back like this...

```
[{"id"=>"8j6OrrEj5EUAqd6qLyM5f4p0xN3DjduYebMJ3",
 "date"=>"2016-07-06", "amount"=>21.41, 
 "name"=>"Debit Card Purchase 07/01 12:13p #4137 UBER US JUL01 YO3SW CA 16184"}, 
 {"id"=>"RkwMDDrkdruO51L5ZPEyCPyzYqVmaeT9ExN4q", "date"=>"2016-07-06", 
  "amount"=>19.18, "name"=>"Debit Card Purchase 07/01 11:07p #4137 UBER US JUL01 HVRD2 CA 16186"}, 
  {"id"=>"QKdMLLjK0jFwZn6ZyM7mC8LZy4VnvOT9BYXzz", "date"=>"2016-07-06",
   "amount"=>16.19, "name"=>"Debit Card Purchase 07/01 03:17p #4137 UBER US JUL01 LIORT CA 16184"}]
```

But when I change my method to

```
   def get_autocomplete_items(params)
     @transaction = current_tenant.transaction
     @trans_array = @transaction.transactions.find_all { |x| /#{Regexp.escape(params[:term])}/i =~ x[:name] }
     render json: @trans_array.map { |trans| trans[:name] }.uniq
   end
```

I am still getting the error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `id' for "[\"Amazon\",\"Mama Maria's Pizzeria\"]":String:
```

Comment: It returns `NoMethodError: undefined method "limit" for #<Array:0x007fdff9231de8>`

Comment: I am using mongoid and :trans_names is a field in the Transaction model

Comment: Can you clarify which version of rails do you use?

Comment: What output will be: `trans_names = ["UBER US JUL01 YO3SW CA 16184"]` `render json: trans_names`

Comment: @farhatmihalko what do you mean? The output should be the completed word. So typing "ube" should output "UBER"

Comment: Put code above to your controller, and check that it works

Comment: This requires you to return objects that respond to `id` and one other method. Right now you are passing an `Array` of `String` rather than an `Array` of `Transactions`. [Source Code](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/blob/master/lib/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/autocomplete.rb#L99)

Comment: @engineersmnky so how can I change the method so that I don't have to show ID being thAt I don't have any ids

Comment: @SupremeA I would not recommend changing the gem as in the future this can get confusing as well as if you are using this elsewhere in your application then it won't function appropriately. What I would do instead is change your code so that these requirements can be satisfied even if that means creating an Array of PORO that can fake the concept of id as well as the method you want to call on the obejct. P.S. just fixing id will not resolve this as it will then fail on trans_names as well.

Comment: @engineersmnky any idea on how I can do that? I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extremely dirty solution and has not been tested at all but because you asked:

```
class ProxyAutoComplete
    def initialize(options)
       @id = option.delete(:id)
       options.each do |method_name,value|
         self.define_singleton_method(method_name) { value } 
       end
    end
    def id
      @id || __id__
    end
end
```

Then when creating the `trans_names` Array you can do so like:

```
trans_names = ["UBER US JUL01 YO3SW CA 16184", 
           "UBER US JUL01 HVRD2 CA 16186", 
           "UBER US JUL01 LIORT CA 16184", 
           "UBER US JUN26 UCF2Z CA 16180", 
           "UBER US JUN27 EZOF5 CA 16180", 
           "UBER US JUN25 BM3LO CA 16179",  
           "UBER US JUN23 5RNBI CA 16177"]
trans_names.map! {|name| ProxyAutoComplete.new({trans_name: name}) }
```

Then you can see this object will respond to both `trans_name` and `id` as required.

```
trans_names.each do |n|
  puts "ID: #{n.id} Name: #{n.trans_name}"
end
#ID: 23039892 Name: UBER US JUL01 YO3SW CA 16184
#ID: 23039832 Name: UBER US JUL01 HVRD2 CA 16186
#ID: 23039760 Name: UBER US JUL01 LIORT CA 16184
#ID: 23039700 Name: UBER US JUN26 UCF2Z CA 16180
#ID: 23039640 Name: UBER US JUN27 EZOF5 CA 16180
#ID: 23039568 Name: UBER US JUN25 BM3LO CA 16179
#ID: 23039508 Name: UBER US JUN23 5RNBI CA 16177
```

This will require you to change this as well

```
class Tenants::TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  #...
  autocomplete :transaction, :trans_name, limit: 5, full: true #second argument must match an option passed to ProxyAutoComplete::new
  #...
end
```

All this is doing is faking the concept of having a database id by allowing you to pass your own or just use the internal id.  It is also creating a method of getting the value back out of the object under any method name you choose. This method name will be the same method name you are passing to the autocomplete method as the second argument

I in no way endorse this concept but it should work appropriately for this functionality (to the extent that it should not fail in that section of the `rails3-jquery-autocomplete` gem)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry it took me long to respond. I will try this out.